# Can't run selenium script remotely

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a python selenium script. I want to run the script on remotely connected(using ssh) PC. when i run the script directly on that PC, it run. but, while i run the same script remotely, it throw error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "crawling_script.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/var/www/html/hariharan/health_grades/chromedriver')
  File "/var/www/html/hariharan/health_grades/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 81, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/var/www/html/hariharan/health_grades/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/var/www/html/hariharan/health_grades/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/var/www/html/hariharan/health_grades/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/var/www/html/hariharan/health_grades/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=73.0.3683.68 (47787ec04b6e38e22703e856e101e840b65afe72),platform=Linux 4.4.0-145-generic x86_64)
```

Please give me a solution to run the selenium python script remotely.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is in the error message: `Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally`.
Can you check what's in the file you are trying to execute (`executable_path=/var/www/html/hariharan/health_grades/chromedriver`)?

Comment: file is available. i can run the script directly on pc. But can't run remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Try `ssh -X`, it forwards graphical output to local machine.